# Proportional width of elements in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` and in it I have `EditText` and `Spinner` elements.
Which attributes I need to adjust so I would get proportional widths: I want `EditText` to take 3/5 and `Spinner` - 2/5 of all available width?

My code looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>

    <Spinner 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried setting `android:layout_weight`, but somehow it does not look "stable" enough for me - when `EditText` has no text - everything looks fine, but as soon as I start entering text into it - it starts expanding and `Spinner` shrinking accordingly...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To literally achieve your request, try setting both widgets' `android:layout_width="0px"`, then set your `android:layout_weight` values as appropriate (`3` and `2`).

Comment: Waaaaw! Thank you !!! I was going crazy trying to find out why I can't rely on WEIGHT with TextEdit and Spinner in one line. +100 ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `layout_width` to `0dip` as well as using `layout_weight`. That should do it.