# Android  Density Problem 

Tags: android, android-layout

Now please consider my below code of android layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout 
                        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
            <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:background="@drawable/default1"
                        android:id="@+id/default1"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                        android:layout_width="180dp" 
                        android:layout_height="45dp" 
                        android:src="@drawable/fc_postyour_best_score_bg"
                        android:id="@+id/postscore"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY">
            </ImageView>   

            <ImageButton
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                        android:layout_width="35dp" 
                        android:layout_height="35dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/fctwitterup"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                        android:id="@+id/twitter"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/postscore"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY">
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                        android:layout_width="35dp" 
                        android:layout_height="35dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/fcfacebookdown"
                        android:id="@+id/fb"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/twitter">
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="160dp" 
                        android:layout_height="40dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/fsremove_ads_down"
                        android:id="@+id/fsremove_ads_down"                     
                        android:layout_below="@id/postscore"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">
            </ImageButton>

            <ToggleButton 
                         android:id="@+id/fsvibrate_on"
                         android:layout_width="135dip"
                         android:layout_height="35dip"
                         android:textOff=""
                         android:textOn=""
                         android:layout_below="@+id/fsremove_ads_down"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:background="@drawable/fsvibrate_on">
            </ToggleButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="210dp" 
                        android:layout_height="60dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/fcplaydown"
                        android:id="@+id/fcplaydown"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            </ImageButton>

            <ToggleButton 
                        android:id="@+id/fcsoundondown"
                        android:layout_width="35dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn=""
                        android:layout_below="@+id/fcplaydown"
                        android:background="@drawable/fcsoundondown">
            </ToggleButton>


        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have problems:

. I have use dp for setting height,margin,width etc. but it varies as devices get change what should I take care for unique layout setting

Comment: try to give it as android:layout_below="@id/fcplaydown"

Comment: u hav placed "+" symbol i removed it because postscore is already there so you need not initialize it again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look over the net and read more about proportional UI in android. Different devices - different resolutions (not mandatory, but in most cases), so how do you want to have same UI on different devices, when you're using static measures. And your RelativeLayout, it is such a mess! Here is an other post, which explains the basic about proportions. [Proportional width of elements in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961154/proportional-width-of-elements-in-linearlayout)

It applies for RelativeLayout also!

Comment: this is because you're using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, you can not use both `layout_centerInParent` and `layout_below`, it leads to mess like that.

Comment: so what's happening here: when you use `layout_enterInParent` the object with **ID=fcplaydown** center on the screen, but then when you try to use **layout_below**, it thinks that **fcplaydown** is aligned top-left. You could see it if you remove the line `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` from your xml code.

Comment: one advice, do not use such a technic, think about of readable code, if you have to change something, you'll need a lot of efforts!

Comment: Thanks for replay--and Sorry for late to replay due to some reason I was out of touch.

Comment: Actually I am new to android development.Can you give some tips for layout designing according to my layout code what should I take care of.........Th@nks In @dvance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. dont use + on id property when setting layout_below

   android:layout_below="@+id/fcplaydown" --> android:layout_below="@id/fcplaydown"
2. Using dp or dip is best option. Images sometimes represent problems if no height and width in dp is defined

Comment: It gives this error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/fcplaydown'). And by the way it works for above all Image Button...    And I cannot get what you said in "2" I have defined height and width ...

Comment: ok, second thing:
problem is with android:layout_centerInParent="true" this option messes things. try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout for those images you want to show one below the other. Hope this works.